# Linux From Scratch, glibc Make error

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu, glibc

I am following the LFS guide 7.2 and I am at section 5.7. When executing the Glibc make, I receive the following error.

```
    -o /mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build/math/s_isnan.os -MD -MP -MF /mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build/math/s_isnan.os.dt -MT /mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build/math/s_isnan.os 
../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64/s_isnan.c:30:1: error: '__EI___isnan' aliased to external symbol '__GI___isnan'
make[2]: *** [/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build/math/s_isnan.os] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.16.0/math'
make[1]: *** [math/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.16.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My GCC version is 4.7.2. What are the steps I should take to correct this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your compiler, see http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14281